# Usage 'base_to_global_rate' and 'base_to_order_rate'

Tags: magento-1.7, sales-order

What is the difference between 'base_to_global_rate' and 'bast_to_order_rate' in an order. When are these fields used?

```
 $data = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId(1000023)->getData();
 var_dump($data);
```

The dump of the order shows following output:

```
array (size=145)
  ...
  'base_shipping_tax_amount' => string '0.6500' (length=6)
  'base_shipping_tax_refunded' => string '0.1666' (length=6)
  'base_subtotal' => string '349.5833' (length=8)
  'base_subtotal_canceled' => null
  'base_subtotal_invoiced' => string '349.5833' (length=8)
  'base_subtotal_refunded' => string '333.0000' (length=8)
  'base_tax_amount' => string '68.9000' (length=7)
  'base_tax_canceled' => null
  'base_tax_invoiced' => string '68.9000' (length=7)
  'base_tax_refunded' => string '65.1789' (length=7)
  'base_to_global_rate' => string '1.0000' (length=6)   // <-------
  'base_to_order_rate' => string '1.0000' (length=6)    // <-------
  'base_total_canceled' => null
  'base_total_invoiced' => string '413.3999' (length=8)
  'base_total_invoiced_cost' => string '0.0000' (length=6)
  'base_total_offline_refunded' => string '402.0741' (length=8)
  'base_total_online_refunded' => null
  'base_total_paid' => string '413.3999' (length=8)
  ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**base_to_global_rate**

Base Currency to Global(GBP) Rate (Ex: For international orders this is USD to GBP Rate)

**base_to_order_rate**

Base Currency to Order Currency(Transaction Currency) Rate (Ex: For international orders in Euros this is EUR to USD Rate)

More info [here](http://suiteweekly.com/2014/10/magento-sales-order-schema/)